# Javascript function run self on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a function, that I run on trigger through an element like `$('.element').tileHeightInit();`.

The function needs to run on `window.load` and `window.resize`. I guess I could define another function inside and run it there, but I figured there was a way to use `this` to run itself or something.

My function:

```
// master function for resizing tile elements
$.fn.tileHeightInit = function ( 
    args = {
        'breakPoint' : breakPoint,
        'container' : container,
        'squared' : squared,
        'blockMargin' : blockMargin,
    })
{
    var breakPoint = args['breakPoint'],
        container = args['container'],
        squared = args['squared'],
        blockMargin = args['blockMargin'];
    
    var gridElements = $(this);

    if (typeof(breakPoint)==='undefined') breakPoint = 767;

    if (typeof(container)==='undefined') container = 'body';

    if (typeof(squared)==='undefined') squared = true;

    if (typeof(blockMargin)==='undefined') blockMargin = 30;

    // return false if no elements found;
    if($(container).find(gridElements).length < 1){
        return false;
    }
    // run if window is larger than breakpoint
    if($(window).width() >= breakPoint){
        $(container).each(function(){
            // height reset. Allows tiles to become smaller on risizing.
            $(this).find(gridElements).each(function(){
                $(this).height('auto');
            })

            // Get an array of all element heights
            var elementHeights = $(this).find(gridElements).map(function() {
                // block height datafield
                var dataHeight = $(this).data('block-height');
                // block widht datafield
                var dataWidth = $(this).data('block-width');
                
                // if squared is enabled
                if(squared === true){

                    // if block is wider than tall, return width as height parameter for quadratic tiles
                    if($(this).height() < $(this).outerWidth() && dataWidth == 1){
                        // return height divided by data-height
                        return $(this).outerWidth();
                    } else{
                        // return width, since tile is wider than it's tall
                        return $(this).height() / dataHeight;
                    }
                } else{
                    // return base height divided by block size;
                    return $(this).height() / dataHeight;
                }
            }).get();

            // Math.max takes a variable number of arguments
            // `apply` is equivalent to passing each height as an argument
            var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);

            // Set each height to the max height                
            $(this).find(gridElements).each(function(){
                // variable for data-height attribute
                var dataHeight = $(this).data('block-height');

                // the missing margin the block would have had if split into more
                var marginDiff = (dataHeight - 1) * blockMargin;
                
                // set height to highest tile * data-height attribute + the margin difference between current block and surrounding blocks
                $(this).height((maxHeight * dataHeight) + marginDiff);
                

            });
        })
    } else{
        // if smaller than breakpoint (colons collapsed)
        $(container).find(gridElements).each(function(){
            // reset height
            $(this).height('auto');
        })
    }
} //  END tileHeightInit();


$(window).resize(function(){
    $('li').tileHeightInit({
        'breakPoint': 500,
    });
})
```

Basically I will be running this function on multiple elements, making writing them all into `resize`, `load` and possible more events seem inefficient.

Comment: Consider using a debounce function to limit the rate at which a function can fire: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: `$(window).resize( $.fn.tileHeightInit.bind(this) );` inside of tileHeightInit

Comment: @JonasW. or he can simply turn his `function { }` into a `() => {}` and omit the `bind(this)` part.

Comment: @JonasW.
Awesome, just what i was looking for!


I also implemented a debounce after watching the function trigger 4000 times in a couple of seconds of resizing.


@AnteJablanAdamović Can you make an example with `() => {}`? 
Am i supposed to change it where i define `$.fn.tileHeightInit = function`?